# How to prove biased estimator with SVD of X

Tags: bias, estimators

[image: Question]

Hi guys, I'm assuming that I am able to use SVD of X to solve this question. So, X = UΣV where U and V are nxn and pxp orthogonal matrices respectively and Σ is an nxp matrix containing the singular values on the diagonal.

I tried to get the expectation of both sides to show the biases. So RHS of the equation would be (1/λ)E[X'X]+E[β̂]=(1/λ)E[VΣ'ΣV']+E[β̂]. 
However, I am unable to prove (1/λ)E[VΣ'ΣV'] is not 0. Is this the right way to tackle this question? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @whuber thanks for the link! I've got another question though. How do I prove the equation in the image? Why would there be a change in estimator when r=p?

Comment: I don't know, because you haven't explained what $r$ refers to.